# convert whole number to a decimal javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm sure this is an easy solution, but I'm not sure where to find this answer being novice in Javascript.

I would like to take a single digit whole number like 6 and change it to a decimal, ex. 6.0 for aesthetic reasons.

What method would I use to accomplish this?

Comment: I think you can adjust that answer to your needs.

Comment: That works. Thanks. How would I only apply this to single digit numbers only?

Comment: You could test whether a number is an integer by doing `Math.floor(n) === n`.